# Intent extra on WallpaperManager's broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-wallpaper

I'm building a wallpaper application.
I have a button which sets the wallpaper.
What I would like to do is to check if the wallpaper is downloaded, if yes set the wallpaper - if not, download and set the wallpaper.

I check if a file with an ID (e.g. `26748.jpg`) exists, if yes I successfully set the wallpaper, if it doesn't exist, I download it - but I'm unable to set it.

I'm have a BroadcastReceiver set up:

```
 <receiver android:name=".SinglePhotoActivity$CheckDownloadComplete">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

which displays a simple saved message:

```
 public static class CheckDownloadComplete extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

The problem is that I have two types of setting the wallpaper: one if the wallpaper is already downloaded, and one if it isn't. I've done a little research and found out that broadcast receivers of this type cannot really contain any intent extras. The only thing I could do is set a description on my *DownloadManager's* request and then check the description in `onReceive`.

So, if the image is already downloaded, I'd like to display a simple Toast. If not, then download it and after, in *OnReceive* after the download has completed run my *setWallpaper* code.

Is there any more proficient way of doing this?

Comment: Where did you read that you cannot have a EXTRA in this Broadcast reveicer?